# How can I get a history of executed SQL queries in Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

If I use the following query

`SELECT query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'database_1';`

I get only the last query executed in database "database_1". How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't keep a history of the executed SQL statements in the database.

What you need to use is the log file. If you set `log_statement = 'all'`, PostgreSQL will log all statements. If you want to view the log file in the database, you can set `log_destination = 'csvlog'` and define a [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) foreign table for the log file.

Comment: Now it doesn't work, because I can't set `log_destination = 'csvlog'` due to an error "parameter "log_destination" cannot be changed now". I've tried to restart the session and the server, but that didn't work. I'll try to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You have to set it in the configuration file `postgresql.conf`, then restart PostgreSQL. Make sure that `logging_collector = on`.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!!